# Windows Phone 8 Map control not displaying when in ContentControl

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, dictionary, contentcontrol

If I try displaying an instance of Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Control.Map in a ContentControl like this:

```
<ContentControl><maps:Map/></ContentControl>
```

the map will not display.  However, if I do not wrap it with a ContentControl, map displays just fine.

I need to wrap it in a container, preferably one that will allow binding to the control.  Hoping to do this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MainMapView, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough using a Border control works fine as follows:

```
<Border Name="MapContentControl" Child="{Binding MainMapView, Mode=OneTime}"></Border>
```